# azure pipelines custom agent with Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out if I can set up an Azure DevOps CD/CI environment for a legacy project, 
for this, in the short term, we need to create Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit build agent. In the medium-to-long term, we will upgrade the entire project.

Before we spend/waste too much time, I'd like to know if that will be possible, I have read that it is possible to create self-hosted agents, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) only lists Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

The agent should work on any platform that can run .NET Core 2.1 applications. Ubuntu 14.04 isn't on that list, and is in fact explicitly unsupported: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/2.1-supported-os.md

Answer (score 0):

For this issue ,agree with **Daniel**.If you want to create a self-hosted Linux agent with Ubuntu 14.04 , I am afraid this is currently not support in azure devops .

It is clearly stated in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#check-prerequisites): The agent is based on **.NET Core 2.1**. You can run this agent on several Linux distributions.

[image]

And the link given by Daniel states that Ubuntu14.04 is no longer supported by .NET Core 2.1.

[image]